# Power Function Manipulation

Tags: self-study, hypothesis-testing, statistical-power

Assume that $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are i.i.d. with the normal distribution
that has mean $μ$ and variance $1$. Suppose that we
wish to test the hypotheses
$$
  H_0: μ ≤ μ_0, \\
  H_1: μ > μ_0.
$$
Consider the test that rejects $H_0$ if $Z≥c$, where $Z$ is defined
in Eq. $(9.1.10)$:
$$
  Z = \frac{\bar{X}-\mu_0}{1/\sqrt{n}}.
$$

a) Show that $\Pr(Z\geq c\mid\mu)$ is an increasing function of $\mu$.

b) Find $c$ to make the test have size $\alpha_0$.

---

This is from de Groot, *Statistics*, 4th edition, exercise 8, page 548.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 1):

[ Although it's tagged as "self-study, and the question doesn't show any substantial work from the OP, I'm answering this because it's quite old and got no responses. ]

**a)** The power function of the proposed test procedure is
\begin{align*}
  \pi(\mu) &= \Pr\{\text{Reject } H_0 \mid \mu\} \\
           &= \Pr\{Z\geq c\mid \mu\} \\
           &= \Pr\left\{ \frac{\bar{X}-\mu_0}{1/\sqrt{n}} \geq  c \;\;\Bigg\vert\;\; \mu \right\} \\
           &= \Pr\left\{ \frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{1/\sqrt{n}} \geq c + \frac{\mu_0-\mu}{1/\sqrt{n}} \;\;\Bigg\vert\;\; \mu \right\} \\
           &= 1-\Phi\!\left(c + \frac{\mu_0-\mu}{1/\sqrt{n}}\right),
\end{align*}
which is an increasing function of $\mu$.

**b)** The test size is $\pi(\mu_0)$. Therefore, $c=\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha_0)$.

```
n <- 25
mu_0 <- 1
alpha_0 <- 0.05
c <- qnorm(1-alpha_0)
power <- function(mu) 1 - pnorm((mu_0-mu)/(1/sqrt(n)) + c)
plot(power, xlim = c(0.7, 2.1))
```